# Copying .xlsx content to .docx in Java

Tags: apache-poi

My current task is to create docx document with some text, table and chart. Currently I'm using Apache POI to generate docx file, but I'm having problem with creating table and chart.

What is actually the best way to do that?

My first idea was to create Excel spreadsheet, put some data, create a chart and somehow copy the entire content to Word document. Is there any way to achieve that?

EDIT 1: Since my app runs on JBoss 7.1, I'm using Apache POI version 3.8, that uses Java 6.

Comment: "and somehow copy the entire content to Word document": Might be possible "somehow". But directly creating the table and the chart using `XWPF` will be much less expensive. See https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xwpf/usermodel/ for examples.

Comment: @AxelRichter thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I use Apache POI 3.8 and I believe those examples use newer library version. I'm running my app on JBoss 7.1 so I'dont think I can use Apache POI 4.0+ in this case.